# Import MYSQl generated .SQL file in MS SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a PHP project in which MYSQL databse is used. I want to convert it to a .NET project. I am generating .sql file of database(from PHP my admin) and want to run it in MS SQL Server. But it is not allowing. How to do it.

Comment: try to get tools that convert mysql to mssql